# Difference in parameter calculation between RothC model description and soiR implementation

Tags: r, model

I am trying to run the *RothC model* using the *SoilR* package.
One of the steps involves the estimation of the effects of moisture on decomposition rates.

According to the [model description](https://www.rothamsted.ac.uk/sites/default/files/RothC_guide_WIN.pdf) (Page 14), the parameter *b* is calculated as:

> if acc. TSMD < 0.444 max.TSMD,
> `b = 1.0` 
> otherwise,
> `b = 0.2 + (0.8) * (max.TSMD - acc.TSMD)/(max.TSMD - 0.444 max.TSMD)`

but the soilR implementation, [fW.RothC.R](https://rdrr.io/cran/SoilR/src/R/fW.RothC.R), is:

`b=ifelse(Acc.TSMD > 0.444*Max.TSMD, 1, (0.2+0.8*((Max.TSMD-Acc.TSMD)/(Max.TSMD-0.444*Max.TSMD))))`

As you can see, the condition has *>* instead of *<*

How to explain this?

I don't have enough reputation to create a tag, but it would be useful to add the tags *soilr* and *rothc*.

Answer (score 1):

the R function is ok. The manual of RothC had an error (or maybe had a minus a a non-visible character after the TSMD sentence).Check the another implementation of rothC (soilassessment), have the same formula.
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/soilassessment/html/carbonTurnover.html

Comment: I think you are right. In the end, I wrote myself a function to apply the model and, to achieve the same results as the manual, you need to apply the formula as in the package (Acc.TSMD > 0.444*Max.TSMD), and not as in the manual.